# Java Restlets - Match arbitrarily long URI path parameter

Tags: java, rest, uri, match, routes

Using [Restlets](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/) you can route URIs using a system based on the [URI template specification](http://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/). I want to be able to route URIs which match the following pattern

```
http://www.blah.com/something/...arbitrarily long path.../somethingelse/
```

So, the following two URIs would be matched and routed the same:

```
http://www.blah.com/something/a/b/c/d/somethingelse/

and:

http://www.blah.com/something/z/y/x/w/v/somethingelse/
```

How can I achieve this using Restlets?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to set up routes is with a Router, like so:

```
router.attach("/path/to/resource", MyResource.class);
```

'attach' returns a [Route](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/Route.html), which has the method [setMatchingMode](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/TemplateRoute.html#setMatchingMode(int)), so you can do this:

```
router.attach("/path/to/resource", MyResource.class).setMatchingMode(Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH);
```

This sets the route to match any URL which starts with the supplied pattern.

I hope that's sufficient for your needs. I'm not aware of any built-in way to match URLs with a particular prefix and a particular suffix. But if that's specifically what you need, you could probably implement your own subclass of Template, Route, etc (I'm not sure which would be needed.)

I'm pretty sure that regex-based routing has been discussed on the Restlet mailing list; you may want to search there.